# jQuery inestedsortable plugin adding css bydefault

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using `inestedsortable` plugin for drag and drop but I see that it is giving some css to the inner `<ul>` by itself like padding which I don't want. How can I disable it?

```
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="sort">
   <span></span>
   <a class='expand'>Group1</a>
   <a style='padding-right:10px; float:right' href='#'>Delete</a>
   <a style='padding-right:10px; float:right' href='#'>Edit</a>
   <ul id="Group1">
    <li id="1" class='sort'>
        <span></span>
        <a href='#'>Patent 1</a>
        <em style='padding-left: 60px;'>The description of patent 1</em>
        <a style='padding-right:10px; float:right' href='#'>Delete</a>
        <a style='padding-right:10px; float:right' href='#'>Edit</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
</ul>
```

The inner `<ul>` gets some style when I check it in firebug.

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot? It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is this the plugin you are talking about? [Nested Sortables](http://code.google.com/p/nestedsortables/) If so, it is no longer maintained; you should probably use jQuery UI instead.

Comment: @Mathletics no not using this one

Comment: Can you link us to the plugin you ARE using?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/nestedsortables/downloads/detail?name=inestedsortable-1.0.1.pack.js&can=2&q=

Comment: That is the same plugin.  It has not been updated in 5 years.

Comment: @Alex W well update of this plugin is not a problem because I can achieve my requirement with this plugin but its adding css to inner ul :(

Answer (score 1):

Actually it was not the problem of that plugin its because of jQuery, if you use this plugin for drag and drop use ol instead of inner ul. Then no padding is applied